# Authenticating Android User through CakePHP Auth

Tags: android, api, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-1.3

I know this is a general question and specifics are better here, but I don't know what specifics to ask yet.

Firstly, does anyone in the community here have experience with building and Android app that authenticates through a CakePHP site that uses the Cake Auth component?

I am currently walking through this tutorial [Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) and I am able to get it to do some things. When trying to login from my app I am getting a "Incorrect username/password" which means that I am making connection to my Cake application, but cannot get any further.

If you will notice in the instructions and the files it handles a value for $salt which has a specific value in the DB they tell you to create. Well with Cake you already have a users table tied to Auth and the $salt value is used by all users and not specific. Any ideas about how to get around this??? This is where I think my glitch is coming from.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using? Form, HTTP, Digest?
What is the version of Cake? The question is labeled 1.3, but if it is a new Cake app I would suggest using CakePHP 2.1+ for the following reasons:

1. The improved Request Handling
2. Ability for Digest Authentication

But if you're just doing a Android version of the existing Cake App, 1.3 + form authentication will do you good. Give us some info about the format that the data is sent and received from the Cake App.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a login action that takes the posted login form sent by your login activity, and if login successful the action redirects you to an XML view or json view, inside your android app you parse the result and welcome the user. Sounds good:-)